# How to find the probability of a $2$ appearing in several dominoes selected

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What I want to find out is that if you have a normal set of $28$ dominoes $(0-6)$ and $5$ of them are chosen randomly, what is the probability that there will be either a $2$ or a $6$ on one of those dominoes?
I have tried finding that $\frac{11}{28}$ is the probability from picking one domino and having a $2$ or $6$ but I don’t know where to go from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which is the opposite probability?! (To not see neiter the $2$, nor the $6$ on the dominos...)

Comment: Your calculation that the probability that one domino contains a 2 or 6 is incorrect.  If a domino has a 2 on it, the other side can be selected in seven ways (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6).  Likewise, if a domino has a 6 on it, the other side can be selected in seven ways.  However, we have counted the domino with a 2 on one side and a 6 on the other side twice.  We only want to count it once, so we must subtract that case, giving $2 \cdot 7 - 1 =  13$ dominos that contain a 2 or a 6.

Comment: Let´s define the events first. 

$A: \textrm{A domino has 2 spots.}$

$B: \textrm{A domino has 6 spots.}$

Then it is aksed for $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. In total there are $\binom{7}2=28$ dominoes. Now we can count the number of dominoes with 2 spots .

$(0,2);(1,2);(2,2);(3,2);(4,2);(5,2);(6,2)$. Thus $P(A)=\frac{7}{28}$. Similar for $B$. Obviously we have one domino which has 2 spots and 6 spots. 

Thus $P(A\cup B)=\frac{7}{28}+\frac{7}{28}-\frac{1}{28}=\frac{13}{28}$

Comment: on *at least one* or on *exactly one*?

Comment: On at least one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A = there will be either a 2 or a 6 on one of those five dominoes

It's more easy to got $P(A^\complement)$

There are 15 dominoes without 2 and 6 $\implies\binom{15}{5}$ ways to select 5 dominoes without 2 and 6

There are 28 dominoes $\implies\binom{28}{5}$ ways to select 5 dominoes

$P(A^\complement)=\frac{\binom{15}{5}}{\binom{28}{5}}=\frac{11}{360}$

$P(A)=1-P(A^\complement)=\frac{349}{360}$